# How can I fix hydration error in authenticating component

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js

I have a authentication component that checks if the user has token or not from localstorage and here is my code :

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useState } from "react";
const Index = (WrappedComponent: any) => {

return (props: any) => {

if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
const Router = useRouter();

      const accessToken = localStorage.getItem("token");
    
    
      if (!accessToken) {
        Router.replace("/authentication/login");
        return null;
      }
    

    
      return <WrappedComponent {...props} />;
    }
    
    // If we are on server, return null
    return null;

};
};

export default Index;
```

And I use it for my components in /pages directory like this :

```
import PageContainer from "../src/components/container/PageContainer";
import FullLayout from "../src/layouts/full/FullLayout";
import ShortList from "@/src/components/dashboard/ShortList";
import withAuth from "@/src/auth";

const Index = () => {
  return (
    <FullLayout>
      <PageContainer title="Sample Page" description="this is Sample page">
        <ShortList />
      </PageContainer>
    </FullLayout>
  );
};

export default withAuth(Index);
```

But I get this Error:
Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

How can I fix this?

My next js version is 13.

I tried using useState but didn't work

Comment: The first render should be the same on the server and client. You could try using cookies instead of local storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the server, `typeof window` will be `undefined`, but on the client, even **before the initial render**, `window` will not be undefined anymore, resulting in a hydration error because your server rendered different HTML than what React now has during hydration.

Because `useEffect` **only** runs on the client, you can check whether you're on the client or server this way:

```js
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Index = (WrappedComponent: any) => {
  return (props: any) => {
    const [isMounted, setIsMounted] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
      setIsMounted(true);
    }, []);

    const Router = useRouter();

    if (!isMounted) {
      // If we are on the server, return null
      return null;
    }

    const accessToken = localStorage.getItem("token");

    if (!accessToken) {
      Router.replace("/authentication/login");
      return null;
    }

    return <WrappedComponent {...props} />;
  };
  
};

export default Index;
```

---

Generally speaking, this check: `if (typeof window !== "undefined")` always leads to errors and does not work as expected.

I recommend this post from Joshua Comeau about react hydration/rehydration issues  https://www.joshwcomeau.com/react/the-perils-of-rehydration

---

Keep in mind that in this example, the Index page will initially be served as completely blank, because it's essentially being client-side rendered now, which may harm SEO.

To fix this, you should store the auth data in cookies and already check in next.js `middleware` whether the user is logged in or not, and potentially redirect inside the middleware instead of on the client.